# Ajax call request are taking longer time to execute

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, xmlhttprequest

In an MVC & knockout.js application call is being made using following function

```
GetCalendar: function (monthYear) {
    var html = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + 'ajax/GetCalendarHTML',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        data: {
            month: monthYear.month, year: monthYear.year
        },
        success: function (cal) {
            $('#cal' + monthYear.month + monthYear.year).html(cal);
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
    return html;
}
```

This  brings data in form for json  which is converted into HTML as below

```
<table cellspacing='0' class='calendar'><thead> <tr class='month-year'><th colspan='7'><span class='month'>March</span><span class='year'>2023</span></th></tr><tr class='weekdays'> <td>Sun</td> <td>Mon</td> <td>Tue</td> <td>Wed</td> <td>Thu</td> <td>Fri</td> <td>Sat</td></tr></thead><tbody border='1'><tr><td class='premonth'></td><td class='premonth'></td><td class='premonth'></td><td style='background-color:#886B29'>1</td><td style='background-color:#886B29'>2</td><td style='background-color:#886B29'>3</td><td style='background-color:#886B29'>4</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>12</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>13</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>14</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>15</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>16</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>17</td><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>18</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#FEF200'>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>25</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:#a02647'>26</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>27</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>28</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>29</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>30</td><td style='background-color:#a02647'>31</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

But these request are sent for each month and takes very long for some reason. some users have reported as long as 5-7 minutes but for me it download withing 1 minute which is still very slow.

Can function be replaced with something new which can download data faster

ajax/GetCalendarHTML?month=2&year=2023

This is a old application developed in 6-7 years back

I converted this to Fetch request but this is not working

```
async function GetCalendar(monthYear) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('${baseURL}ajax/GetCalendarHTML?month=${monthYear.month}&year=${monthYear.year}', {
      cache: 'default',
      method: 'GET'
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }

    const cal = await response.text();
    $('#cal' + monthYear.month + monthYear.year).html(cal);
    return cal;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching calendar:', error);
  }
}
```

You can see in below screenshot status remain pending and it take about 1 minute in my case and some client say it take about 5 minutes to show all calendar items
[image]

I have not been able to find the reason for delay

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a client side makes this several minutes delay. It is usually a server side problem, or a data base server query needs to be optimazed. So continue to use Ajax , only maybe make  it clear, by removing this at all

```
 cache: true,
        data: {
            month: monthYear.month, year: monthYear.year
        },
```

and adding data to url

```
 url: '${baseURL}ajax/GetCalendarHTML?month=${monthYear.month}&year=${monthYear.year}'
```

Comment: It doesnt make any difference to performance of function it still take ages to show all calendar items